# SAS delete totals and headers

Tags: sas

I'm running this procedure in sas:

> PROC PRINT data = test; by a; var a b; sum b; RUN;

A runnable example would be:

```
proc print data = sashelp.shoes; 
  by region; 
  var stores sales; 
  sum sales; 
run;
```

In my results I'm getting headers and totals for each record. How can i remove the headers and totals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `by` statement is splitting your results into sections, each section will be labelled with a header.  You can remove the `by` statement to just print it all as one large block.

The `sum` statement is creating the totals, just remove that line and they will disappear.

```
proc print data = sashelp.shoes; 
  var stores sales; 
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually want groups by the variable `a`?  If not, then remove `by a;`.

Answer (score 0):

How about a PROC TABULATE?

```
PROC SORT DATA = SASHELP.CLASS OUT = CLASS;
     BY AGE;
RUN;

PROC TABULATE DATA = CLASS OUT = TEST2 ; 
    CLASS AGE; 
    VAR HEIGHT; 
    TABLE AGE, HEIGHT; 
RUN;
```